# How to determine trial booking conversion - google sheets

Tags: woocommerce, google-sheets

**Introduction**

Many sites use WooCommerce as a plugin for their WordPress site and so do we :). We've linked all purchases to google sheets, so I can do some analyses.

Our goal is get a many children physically active as we can and we have gym classes for very young children with they parents. To teach them the basics of the fun of physical activity

**What I would like to do**

I would like to know, how many free trial classes actually convert to paying customers and what the average timespan is between booking a trial class and becoming a member

**The data that I have**

I have the following columns which are necessary for this, I believe:

- Datestamp
- paymentID (is empty when booking a free trial class)
- Price (is 0,00 whem booking a free trial class)
- childsName (Unique in combination with parentsEmailadress, but recurs every month in the list once a membership is active)
- parentsEmailadress (may have several children)
- OrderName (has the string "trial" or "Membership")

I've made some dummy data in the following sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lWzQbXMU4qRLp_2qiQ_qsq57nPMy2RG8AHDMGKW626E/edit?usp=sharing

**Possible solution**

My guess is that I should:

1. make a column in which I combine the childs name and the emailadress
2. Make a TRUE of FALSE column to check if order is trial class or not
3. Make a column to find the first Unique child-emailadres combination in previous orders (*How do I do that?!* - *Vlookup?*)

and than

- if this is found than check again if this is a trial class order.
- If it is a trial class order than it should determine the amount of days between the trial class order and the non-trial class order and display the amount of days
- if this is another normal order than leave empty(it's just a membership order)
- if the emailadres is not found than display "direct" (it's a directly bought membership)

I did 1 and 2 and tried 3 with: 
=ALS(H2=0;VERT.ZOEKEN(G2;A:G;1;ONWAAR);) (in Dutch)
=IF(H2=0;V.LOOKUP(G2;A:G;1;FALSE);) (possible translation)

But this doesn't work.

Really hope some can point me in the right direction!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @pnuts Thank you and I see what you are saying. The question is probably too broad. A point in the right direction would have been great, but thanks to Diego I'm super happy!
Hope this question will help many more. Because many businesses use trial classes, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that trial classes have a price of 0, there's no need to create another column to identify those cases–just check the price. To the source data we'll add the "Client ID" column that you created in Column G of your sample sheet. (Ideally, you'll come up with an client ID system, but this works.) Now, create a new sheet that will be your dashboard and let's add a few columns:

1. **Client ID** This grabs only the unique values from the Client IDs in Sheet2 as we don't want users to be repeated in our dashboard. (Column A, row 1... for all others place the formulas in row 2).
   `=UNIQUE(Sheet2!G:G)`
2. **Did they trial?** This will tell you `TRUE`/`FALSE` if the client did a trial. (Column B).
   `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(Dashboard!A2, FILTER(Sheet2!G:G, Sheet2!C:C=0), 0))`
3. **Did they convert?** This will tell you `TRUE`/`FALSE` if the client converted from trial to paid. (In cases where they did not do a trial, it will be blank.) (Column C).
   `=IF(Dashboard!B2, ISNUMBER(MATCH(Dashboard!A2, FILTER(Sheet2!$G:$G, Sheet2!$C:$C>0), 0)), "")`
4. **Date of First Trial** The date of the first trial. If none exists, will be blank. (Column D).
   `=IFERROR(MIN(FILTER(Sheet2!$A:$A, Sheet2!$G:$G=Dashboard!A2, Sheet2!$C:$C=0)))`
5. **Date of First Paid Course** The date of the first paid course. If none exists, will be blank. (Column E).
   `=IFERROR(MIN(FILTER(Sheet2!$A:$A, Sheet2!$G:$G=Dashboard!A2, Sheet2!$C:$C>0)))`
6. **Days from First Trial to First Paid** The number of days between the first paid course and the first trial course. If one of those values doesn't exist, then will be blank. (Column F).
   `=IF(ISDATE(Dashboard!E2), Dashboard!E2-Dashboard!D2, "")`

Now you can answer several questions:

- **How many clients used a free trial?** `=COUNTIF(Dashboard!B:B, TRUE)`
- **How many free trials converted?** `=COUNTIF(Dashboard!C:C, TRUE)`
- **Average number of days from first trial to first paid?** `=AVERAGE(Dashboard!F:F)`

[image]

Comment: WOW, Diego! Thank you so much!!! I'll look into this over the weekend and show you the results :) THANK YOU for your time and effort!!!

Comment: Works like a charm AND gives me the ability to dig even deeper. Thank you so much!! I just learned that we've been able to give more than 1000 hours of free physical activity classes since september last year. HAPPY :)